# Python string encoding

Tags: python, string, encoding

I'm trying to write an html but I have some problems with the characters encoding.

this is my description:

> Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime Dual Sim Il Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime è
>   uno smartphone Dual SIM Dual Standby con scocca monoblocco basato sul
>   sistema operativo Android 4.4.2, con supporto alle reti UMTS/GSM e
>   connettività [...]

but when I write it using

> self.wfile.write(desc)

I receive this error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   1086: ordinal not in range(128)

The problem is with the **à** characters.

I need to find I way to encode it and pass to the function

I don't want to use something like

```
footer=footer.replace("à","a")
```

I need a general method that can works for all characters and if is possible the method must keep the accent.

Comment: Try UnicodeDammit. Part of beautiful soup. from bs4 import UnicodeDammit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using UTF-8? UTF strings have many of the same properties as an ASCII string.

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

```
# Assignment
>>> s = u' alle reti UMTS/GSM e connettività'

# As a function parameter
>>> def test(string):
...     print string

>>> test(u'connettività')

connettività
```